# Is there any existing way to move a CSV file from SFTP to a media folder for recipient to download?

Tags: marketing-cloud, automationstudio, sftp

I have a specific business need for an automation that would be triggered by a CSV file being sent to our SFTP. I then would like the SAME file to be, not necessarily attached, but a download link to the SAME file for the email recipient.

1. User uploads a CSV file
2. CSV file upload triggers automation (done)
3. Move THAT file (the one uploaded) to a Media file (public facing) for the recipient to be able to click and download.

I have looked into the %%=AttachFile operation but is doesn't seem to be working. Is there something simple I am missing. Please let me know if this is not enough information.

Comment: Using AttachFile is a feature that comes with a cost. You need to contact your account representative, otherwise it is not enabled. And sending with attachments is considered to have an impact on your deliverability score, keep that in mind.

Comment: Oh yeah not an attachment, just a URL to taht file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Johannes](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/52639/johannes-schapdick) correctly states, you will need to purchase file attachments, to be able to work with CSV files in emails. Also, I will not recommend attaching such files to emails, as they might grow quite huge. AttachFile is more suited for PDFs and alike.

What about utilising a TXT Code Resource in Cloud Pages?
[image]

Using Ampscript, you will be able to fetch the rows you have just uploaded, and present them in a comma separated manner in the file. Within the email you send, you will have a dynamic link ensuring that the code resource only returns the rows which are for the recipient to receive.

Comment: Actually, and sorry, I don't want to attach a file, just transfer it from the SFTP to the media folder so I can use a dynamic URL for the recipient to receive it.

Comment: @scoopzilla My solution will indeed allow you to supply a custom URL, which will allow the recipient to download the CSV file, as it will be generated dynamically by the code resource.

Comment: do you know of any resources that could help me accomplish this?